# Android onActivityResult set selected row

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I was having some problem when trying to detect the selected row from list view in a pop up window. Here is the part where I onclick the row, then open up another intent:

```
private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendee_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_dName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayName);

            viewHolder.btn_scan = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dName.setText(attendeeList.get(position)
                .getAccountName().trim());

        viewHolder.btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then when onActivityResult():

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            if(contents.equals("QRCode1")){

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "QR code does not match. Please make sure you attended the correct event.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

If the contents is QRCode1, I wanted to do something with the first row. If it's QRCode2, then I wanted to do something with second row.

However, I not sure how should I get the row number. Should I pass it from the onClick?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ideas? Or am I doing in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) on your ListView in the Activity / Fragment?

There you would have a method onItemClick and get, among other things, the position of the clicked item

Comment: Because I got a button inside the list item row. So when the button on click, I will navigate to QR code scan intent. If the item row is selected, I will need to navigate to dial intent.

Comment: Oh ,okay. In your Adapter you could then use the setTag() method.
[Here](https://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/) is one tutorial where someone uses a button in his listView using setTag()